# reshaping a view of a n-dimensional array without using reshape

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

**tl;dr**  Can I reshape a view of a numpy array from 5x5x5x3x3x3 to 125x1x1x3x3x3 without using numpy.reshape?

I would like to perform a sliding window operation (with different strides) to a volume (size of MxMxM).  The sliding window array can be generated with the use of [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py), as previously suggested by [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936620/using-strides-for-an-efficient-moving-average-filter) and [Eickenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691947/3d-sliding-window-operation-in-theano), and demonstrated in the below code snippet, which uses a [helper method from skimage](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/util/shape.py) that uses `as_strided`.

The output from this helper method gives me a shape of NxNxNxnxnxn, but I'd prefer the shape to be N^3x1xnxnxn.  While I can use np.reshape to achieve this, np.reshape is slow if the volume gets large (> 100x100x100), which I'm not sure why.  I thought I can use as_stride to reshape the output, but numpy crashes (code snippet below).  Any ideas on how I can get a view of the output from the helper method as N**3x1xnxnxn without using np.reshape?

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
l = 15
s = 3
X = np.ones((l,l,l))      
print('actual shape',X.shape)
view = skimage.util.shape.view_as_blocks(X,(s,s,s))    
print('original view',view.shape)

new_shape = ((l/s)**3,1,1,s,s,s)
print('new view',new_shape)    

view_correct = view.reshape(new_shape)
print(view_correct.shape)
print('coord:','124,0,0,2,2,2','value:',view_correct[124,0,0,2,2,2])

view_incorrect = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(view, shape=new_shape)
print(view_incorrect.shape)
print('coord:','124,0,0,2,2,2','value:',view_incorrect[124,0,0,2,2,2])
```

Comment: `view_as_blocks` uses `as_strided` with matching `strides` and `shape` to make new view.  And then you apply `as_strided` again, with a different `shape` (and different `ndim`), without changing `strides`.  Shouldn't you be applying `as_strided` directly to `X` - with correct `strides` and `shape`?

Comment: short answer is: no, it is not possible. If you want 'flat' dimension, you can't use view on original tensor for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took an example from `view_as_blocks`, and tried your style of reshape:

```
A = np.arange(4*4).reshape(4,4)
B = view_as_blocks(A, block_shape=(2, 2))
print(A.__array_interface__)
print(B.__array_interface__)

C = B.reshape((2*2,2,2))
print(C.__array_interface__)
```

producing:

```
{'typestr': '<i4', 'data': (153226600, False), 'shape': (4, 4),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')], 'version': 3, 'strides': None}
{'typestr': '<i4', 'data': (153226600, False), 'shape': (2, 2, 2, 2),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')], 'version': 3, 'strides': (32, 8, 16, 4)}
{'typestr': '<i4', 'data': (150895960, False), 'shape': (4, 2, 2),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')], 'version': 3, 'strides': None}
```

The `data` pointer for `A` and `B` is the same; `B` is a view on `A`.

But the pointer for `C` is different.  It is a copy.  That explains why it takes so long in your case.

---

Lets do that a little differently:

```
A = np.arange(4*4).reshape(4,4)
B = view_as_blocks(A, block_shape=(2, 2))
print(A.__array_interface__)
print(B.__array_interface__)

C = B.reshape((2*2,1,2,2))
print(C.__array_interface__)

D = as_strided(B, shape=(2*2,1,2,2))
print(D.__array_interface__)

print(B[1,1,:,:])
print(C[3,0,:,:])
print(D[3,0,:,:])
```

producing

```
1254:~/mypy$ python3 skshape.py 
{'strides': None, 'typestr': '<i4', 'version': 3, 
 'data': (154278744, False), 'shape': (4, 4), 'descr': [('', '<i4')]}
{'strides': (32, 8, 16, 4), 'typestr': '<i4', 'version': 3, 
 'data': (154278744, False), 'shape': (2, 2, 2, 2), 'descr': [('', '<i4')]}
{'strides': None, 'typestr': '<i4', 'version': 3, 
 'data': (155705400, False), 'shape': (4, 1, 2, 2), 'descr': [('', '<i4')]}
{'strides': (32, 8, 16, 4), 'typestr': '<i4', 'version': 3, 
 'data': (154278744, False), 'shape': (4, 1, 2, 2), 'descr': [('', '<i4')]}

[[10 11]
 [14 15]]
[[10 11]
 [14 15]]
[[  154561960 -1217783696]
 [         48        3905]]
```

Again the reshape creates a copy.  The 2nd `as_strides` returns a view, but the striding is screwed up.  It is looking at memory outside the original data buffer (that's part of why playing with strides on your own is dangerous).

---

In my example, look at the first corner value of each block

```
print(B[:,:,0,0])
print(C[:,0,0,0])

[[ 0  2]
 [ 8 10]]
[ 0  2  8 10]
```

For `B`, the rows increase by 8, columns by 2; that's reflected in the `(32,8)` (4*8,4*2) striding.

But in `C` the steps are (2,6,2) - striding can't do that.

From this I conclude that the reshape is impossible without copy.

Comment: hpaulj, thank you for the comprehensive explanation. the of use __ array_interface__ was really useful in helping me to understand the problem.

Comment: revisited this again(!) after 4 years. finally added the "accepted answer". Thanks again for taking the time to answer this.