# numpy reshape and tile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert a vector from A-L to something like this with pandas and numpy built in functions without loops (tile, repeat and reshape). But I cannot wrap my head around

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
0   A   A   A   A   E   E   E   E   I   I   I   I
1   B   B   B   B   F   F   F   F   J   J   J   J
2   C   C   C   C   G   G   G   G   K   K   K   K
3   D   D   D   D   H   H   H   H   L   L   L   L
4   A   A   A   A   E   E   E   E   I   I   I   I
5   B   B   B   B   F   F   F   F   J   J   J   J
6   C   C   C   C   G   G   G   G   K   K   K   K
7   D   D   D   D   H   H   H   H   L   L   L   L
```

Do you have any ideas how I could do that without loops ?

what I have tried so far:

```
a = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K',  'L'])
b = a.reshape(3,4)

np.repeat(b, 4).reshape(4,12)
```

gives me:

```
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
       ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
       ['J', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

EDIT: Some background. Depending on the number of samples and the layout we choose. A machine, creates plates (like in this [image](http://www.bioregio-stern.de/files/styles/zoom/public/attachments/pressrelease/te-zhaw100.jpg?itok=Z2yjE4rh)). We can do consecutive operations (add more chemicals etc.) and based on the previous layout, unique combinations are obtained. Afterwards the machine measures e.g. concentration in each well and I would like to link the output to the conditions in each well. Because the machine can measure e.g. concentration after each step, a lot of data can be generated and I am trying to find a generic solution without too many loops.

Comment: `reshape` often returns a view, so takes near-0 time (but see [when-will-numpy-copy-the-array-when-using-reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995289/when-will-numpy-copy-the-array-when-using-reshape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array(list('abcdefghijkl'.upper()))  # your "vector"
>>> np.repeat(np.tile(x.reshape(-1, 4), 2).T, 4, axis=1)
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
       ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

It first reshapes it so that you have 4 characters in each column, then duplicates them. Then you transpose it so you have the correct rows/columns and finally you just repeat every character 4 times.

Step-by-step it looks like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x
array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> x.reshape(-1, 4)
array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
       ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> np.tile(_, 2)
array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
       ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
       ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> _.T
array([['A', 'E', 'I'],
       ['B', 'F', 'J'],
       ['C', 'G', 'K'],
       ['D', 'H', 'L'],
       ['A', 'E', 'I'],
       ['B', 'F', 'J'],
       ['C', 'G', 'K'],
       ['D', 'H', 'L']],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> np.repeat(_, 4, axis=1)
array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
       ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L']],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> pd.DataFrame(_)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11
0  A  A  A  A  E  E  E  E  I  I   I  I
1  B  B  B  B  F  F  F  F  J  J   J  J
2  C  C  C  C  G  G  G  G  K  K   K  K
3  D  D  D  D  H  H  H  H  L  L   L  L
4  A  A  A  A  E  E  E  E  I  I   I  I
5  B  B  B  B  F  F  F  F  J  J   J  J
6  C  C  C  C  G  G  G  G  K  K   K  K
7  D  D  D  D  H  H  H  H  L  L   L  L
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for my sloppy question. I made a mistake while uploading

Comment: Wow, that is a really comprehensive answer. I will try to understand it without copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJKL"))

a
# array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'], 
#       dtype='<U1')

np.repeat(np.tile(a.reshape(3,4), 2).T, 4, axis=1)
#array([['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
#       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
#       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
#       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L'],
#       ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'I'],
#       ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'J', 'J', 'J', 'J'],
#       ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'K', 'K', 'K', 'K'],
#       ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L']], 
#      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for my sloppy question. I made a mistake while uploading

Comment: Interesting to see the difference in the reshape arguments.