# Numpy reshape - copying data or not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am reading about numpy's reshape method. Here is the quote:

> Note that for this (i.e. reshaping) to work, the size of the initial array must match
> the size of the reshaped array. Where possible, the reshape method
> will use a no-copy view of the initial array, but with noncontiguous
> memory buffers this is not always the case.

I did a few simple tests and it seems `reshape` indeed **does not create a copy**, the memory is shared.

So what does that part here mean "but with noncontiguous memory buffers this is not always the case"? What is an example where `reshape` does create a copy of the data? And what are the rules really i.e. when exactly does it create a copy and when not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will numpy copy the array when using reshape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995289/when-will-numpy-copy-the-array-when-using-reshape)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Seems that question/answer does talk about the same thing but I don't really understand it. What are they talking about there? I need some simple explanation when is it doing a copy and when not. I will reread that answer anyway.

Comment: What is this order C and order F? And then it says "It will do a copy if the initial order is so 'messed up' that it can't return values like this." What does that mean?! Sounds totally informal to me.

Comment: C order and F(ortran) order refers to [row-major and column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) of multidimensional arrays. Contiguous means that you can the array is stored as one "block" in memory. You use special indexing to extract non-contiguous values from an array (e.g. transposition). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998223/what-is-the-difference-between-contiguous-and-non-contiguous-arrays

Answer (score 4):

## Example of a `view` vs `copy`

Here is an example of a copy being created for a reshape operation. We can check if two arrays share memory or not with `np.share_memory`. If `True` then one of them is a view of the other and if `False` then one of them is a copy of the other and is stored in a separate memory. Meaning, any operations on one don't reflect on the other.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
b = a.T

arr1 = a.reshape((-1,1))
print('Reshape of original is a view:', np.shares_memory(a, arr1))

print('Transpose sharing memory:', np.shares_memory(a,b))

arr2 = b.reshape((-1,1))
print('Reshape of transpose is a view:', np.shares_memory(b, arr2))
```

```
Reshape of original is a view: True    #<- a, a.reshape share memory
Transpose sharing memory: True         #<- a, a.T share memory
Reshape of transpose is a view: False  #<- a.T, a.T.reshape DONT share memory
```

## EXPLANATION:

#### How numpy stores arrays?

Numpy stores its ndarrays as contiguous blocks of memory. Each element is stored in a sequential manner every n bytes after the previous.

(images referenced from this [excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034237/how-does-numpys-transpose-method-permute-the-axes-of-an-array))

So if your 3D array looks like this  -

```
np.arange(0,16).reshape(2,2,4)

#array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],
#
#       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

[image]

Then in memory its stores as -

[image]

When retrieving an element (or a block of elements), NumPy calculates how many `strides` (of 8 bytes each) it needs to traverse to get the next element `in that direction/axis`. So, for the above example, for `axis=2` it has to traverse 8 bytes (depending on the `datatype`) but for `axis=1` it has to traverse `8*4` bytes, and `axis=0` it needs `8*8` bytes.

> Almost all numpy operations depend on this nature of storage of the arrays. So, to work with an array that can comprise of non-contiguous blocks of memory, numpy is sometimes forced to create copies instead of views.

#### Why reshape may create a copy sometimes?

Coming back to the example that I show above with array `a` and `a.T`, let's look at the first example. We have an array `a` which is stored as a contiguous block of memory as below -

[image]

Since an array needs to be stored in a contiguous manner so that other numpy operations can be properly applied, it is forced to create a copy of the numpy array since its really difficult to keep a track of the memory associated with the original elements for subsequent operations. This is why the `a.T` gets a reshape output as a copy in this case.

Hopefully, this should explain your query. I am not that great at articulating so do let me know what part is confusing to you and I can edit my answer for a clearer explanation.

Comment: just elaborating on my answer, please give me a minute :)

Comment: OK... But your example raises another question - what does (-1,1) mean in reshape? :) I didn't know we can use negative numbers there. `a.reshape((-1,1))` ?!

Comment: It means that reshape the array such that (all elements, 1) is the shape.. `-1` is just a way for us to tell numpy to auto compute the length in that direction.

Comment: So, if i had (5,4) which is 20 elements  and i say reshape to (-1,2) then its going to reshape it to (10,2) because it auto calculates that 10 elements will be needed on that axis

Comment: I think I get it better now. Thank you. You have a bug on your last line: `Reshape of transpose is a copy: False` You should print message `'Reshape of transpose shares memory:'`

Comment: thanks, could you elaborate the bug? the code is running for me

Comment: It's working but printing the wrong thing. If it shares memory then it's not a copy.

Comment: So it should be `print('Reshape of transpose is a copy:', not np.shares_memory(b, arr2))`

Comment: No thats the point. I wanted to show that a, a.reshape share memory.. and a, a.T share memory .. BUT a.T and a.T.reshape DONT share memory... If it shares memory then its a view .. if they dont share memory they are a copy

Comment: added comments.

Comment: No, the message is wrong. Think about it. Now the 3rd message contradicts the 3rd comment.

Comment: You should do:  `print('Reshape of transpose is a copy:', not np.shares_memory(b, arr2))` because something is a copy of something iff it does not share memory with it.

Comment: AHHH, ok i get what you mean .. sorry!!

Comment: :) Yeah... everything else is fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added the print statements later and didn't realize they dont make sense with the True/False :) thanks for pointing that out. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to repeat the core of my linked answer, and say that `transpose` is the most likely case where `reshape` will produce a copy.

But then I thought of a case where the `view` is produces a non-contiguous selection:

```
In [181]: x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [182]: x1 = x[::2,::2]
In [183]: x
Out[183]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
In [184]: x1
Out[184]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 8, 10]])
In [185]: x1[0,0]=100
In [186]: x
Out[186]: 
array([[100,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15]])
```

`x1`, created with basic indexing, is a `view`.  But a reshape of it is a copy:

```
In [187]: x2 = x1.reshape(-1)
In [188]: x2
Out[188]: array([100,   2,   8,  10])
In [189]: x2[0] = 200
In [190]: x1
Out[190]: 
array([[100,   2],
       [  8,  10]])
In [191]: x
Out[191]: 
array([[100,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15]])
```

A simple test for a copy is to look at the `ravel`.  `ravel` is a `reshape`; if the ravel isn't the same as the originals, or a subset of it, it's a copy.

```
In [192]: x.ravel()
Out[192]: 
array([100,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,
        13,  14,  15])
In [193]: x1.ravel()
Out[193]: array([100,   2,   8,  10])    # x1 is a view, but a reshape is a copy
In [194]: xt = x.T
In [195]: xt
Out[195]: 
array([[100,   4,   8,  12],
       [  1,   5,   9,  13],
       [  2,   6,  10,  14],
       [  3,   7,  11,  15]])
In [196]: xt.ravel()   # xt is a view, but its reshape is a copy
Out[196]: 
array([100,   4,   8,  12,   1,   5,   9,  13,   2,   6,  10,  14,   3,
         7,  11,  15])
```

selecting two rows is a view, and its reshape is one too:

```
In [197]: x[:2].ravel()
Out[197]: array([100,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7])
In [198]: x[:2].ravel()[0]=200
In [199]: x
Out[199]: 
array([[200,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15]])
```

but not when selecting two columns:

```
In [200]: x[:,:2].ravel()
Out[200]: array([200,   1,   4,   5,   8,   9,  12,  13])
In [201]: x[:,:2].ravel()[0]=150
In [202]: x
Out[202]: 
array([[200,   1,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15]])
```

As for predicting a copy without actually doing it - I'd depend more on experience than some code (which I attempted in the linked answer).  I have a good idea of how the data is layed out, or can easily test for it.

Keep in mind when this copy/no-copy is important.  As I showed, the copy case keeps us from modifying the original array.  Whether that's good or not depends on the situation.  In other cases we don't really care.  The performance cost of a copy isn't that great.